# Selected list properties to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a list with 8 properties and values. But I would like to get only some of them where IOType=="O" and convert to json format.

[image: list]

If i use like LINQ

```
excelIO.Where(m => m.IOType == "O").Select(m => new ExcelBo { InterfaceColId = m.InterfaceColId, IOValue = m.IOValue }).ToList();
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(excelBoList);
```

Current output

```
[{"FunctionWBId":0,"ExcelCellNo":null,"IOType":null,
"InterfaceColId":"txtPrmServicTaxAmt","IOValue":"0.00","DataType":null,
"Status":null,"FunctionWBMap":null},
    {"FunctionWBId":0,"ExcelCellNo":null,"IOType":null,
"InterfaceColId":"txtPrmStampDutyAmt","IOValue":"10.00",
"DataType":null,"Status":null,"FunctionWBMap":null}]
```

Desired output : "InterfaceColId" value will be a String and 'IOValue" value will be a value.

```
[{"txtPrmServicTaxAmt":"0.00","txtPrmStampDutyAmt" :"10.00"}]
```

Please help me to give desired ouput?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].  For us to be able to help you, we should be able to copy your example into a c# code file, compile it, and test it.  As it is, your variable `excelBoList` is undefined.  You are also not passing the return of `excelIO.Where...` to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way is to store your values into dictionary instead of list:

```
var excelBoDict = excelIO.Where(m => m.IOType == "O")
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.InterfaceColId, y => y.IOValue);
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(excelBoDict);
```

This will be serialized as:

```
[{"txtPrmServicTaxAmt":"0.00","txtPrmStampDutyAmt" :"10.00"}]
```

It will work if you does not have repeating values of `InterfaceColId`. If so, I guess you need to implement your own serializer based on [`JsonTextWriter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsontextwriter.htm) ([example usage](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/WriteJsonWithJsonTextWriter.htm)) in following way:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    foreach(var item in excelBoList)
    {
        writer.WritePropertyName(item.InterfaceColId);
        writer.WriteValue(item.IOValue);
    }
    writer.WriteEnd();
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}

var result = sb.ToString();
```

Note, that if you will have multiple properties with single name - this may cause unpredictable behaviour.